# List does not update when modifying the existing elements using replaceAll()

Tags: java

This is what my code looks like:

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>(); 

l1.add("one");
l1.add("two");
l1.add("three");
l1.add("four");
  
for(String str : l1){
    if(str.equals("four")){
     str = str.replaceAll(str,"five");
    }
}
System.out.println(l1);
```

As you can see, I have used `replaceAll()` and expect the output as `[one,two,three,five]` but it is showing `[one,two,three,four]`.

Although I checked that `str` is equivalent to `"four"`, it should replace the value with `"five"` but it doesn't update the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not touching the list at all, so of course it doesn't update. You need to get rid of the element you want to replace, and insert `str` in its place. Or take a look at the [ArrayList Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and see if there's any methods that will help you do what you want.

Comment: When you receive the String `str` to check it's value, this `str` isn't a pointer to the item in the list that would have changed the item value with _C_ ou _C++_ languages.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`List::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
list.replaceAll(s -> s.equals("four") ? "five" : s);

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[one, two, three, five, five]
```

Comment: I [hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64575129/5221149) your answer. As compensation, you got my up-vote. 

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Java 8 or later, do as shown in [answer by Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64574747/5221149):

> You may want to use [`List::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method:
>
> ```java
> List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
> list.replaceAll(s -> s.equals("four") ? "five" : s);
>
> System.out.println(list);
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```java
> [one, two, three, five, five]
> ```

Otherwise use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

```java
for (ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    String s = iter.next();
    if (s.equals("four"))
        iter.set("five");
}
```

You *could* use an index loop, like shown in another answer, but that will perform badly with some `List` implementations, e.g. [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), so I wouldn't recommend it. Even if the list is currently known to be an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), that might change in the future, so better code for it now.

```java
// I don't recommend this
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    if (list.get(i).equals("four"))
        list.set(i, "five");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend iterating over the list this way:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
   strings.add("one");
   strings.add("two");
   strings.add("three");
   strings.add("four");
   for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
     if(strings.get(i).equals("four")) {
       strings.set(i, "five");
     }
   }

   System.out.println(strings);
  }
```

Your solution fails because replaceAll returns a string which you put in str and then you don't do anything with it when you actually want to set the "four" element to a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Java is working as designed, so let me try to explain why and how it works this way.

strings are objects.

variables of any object type (so, everything, except `int`, `double` and the other 6 primitives) are **references**.

references are like treasure maps. X marks the spot.

objects are like treasures.

`x = foo` is you wiping out your treasure map and drawing a new one. If `x` was a map to some treasure, after this, that treasure is **entirely unaffected** - all you've done is wiped out your treasure map and overwritten it with a map to some different treasure (And that treasure is also unaffected). We're just messing with the maps here, not with the treasure.

`x.foo()` - That dot (`.`) is how you express 'follow the map and dig down' in java. This will 'send a message' to the object and that may or may not affect that object. It depends on the method. Something like `"hello".length()` does not change the string. Something like `myObj.setName("Joe");` definitely does change the treasure that your `myObj` treasure map is a map to.

`str.replaceAll` **does not change the treasure**. That method makes an entirely new treasure, which is a copy of the treasure you send that message to, except with the replacement applied. That's because string objects are *immutable* - **none** of java.lang.String's method change the treasure. By design. That's why `replaceAll` returns a String in the first place (that'd be the modified clone).

So, to go through it line by line:

1. `for (String str : l1)`

This says: Grab a new blank piece of paper and put `this is called str` at the top. Then, take your existing treasure map called `l1`, follow it, and dig. It contains 4 treasure maps (one to a treasure "one", one to a treasure "two", etcetera). For each map you find here, copy the map to your brand new blank paper labelled `str`, wiping out whatever was there if needed, and run the code in the {}.

2. `str = str.replaceAll(str, "five");`

This says: Follow your `str` map and dig. Then, wipe out your str map, ask the treasure to make a modified clone of itself and bury in the sand somewhere, and then update your `str` map to point at this new treasure.

3. `}}` - close the if and the for

We now loop back to the top which means your modified treasure map is discarded, and therefore that cloned treasure? Nobody has a map anymore. It is lost in the sand. Eventually the garbage collector will get rid of it.

### Okay so how do I fix it

By calling `l1.set()` or `l1.add()`.

Alternatively, make sure your list consists of **mutable** objects and mutate them. `StringBuilder` is a mutable string-like concept, you could use that.

### An additional note

Even after fixing your list problem, your code is still broken. `replaceAll` is a very badly named method. Its first argument is interpreted as a regular expression. You don't want that. You are looking for `replace`. This **also** replaces every occurrence, but it does NOT try to interpret the needle argument (the first argument) as a regexp, it just treats it as raw characters. More generally of course, `str = str.replace(str, "five");` would be better written as `str = "five";`.

### But... why does java works this way??

Let's go back to that string treasure. As I said, none of the methods change it. That means you can *hand out copies of your treasure map with wild abandon, caring not one iota as to who gets a copy of it*. Your treasure is impervious to damage. It cannot be moved, destroyed, or otherwise messed with.

That's a good thing, because if other code could mess with it, then either I have to go through a lot of effort to document how you can't mess with my treasure or the code breaks, or, I have to clone the treasure every time I need to hand it off to somebody (anytime you pass a string as argument to another method, or return a string, you're handing a copy of your treasure map out to something else). The sheer amount of time and memory wasted with all those copies would be quite problematic!

Perhaps you think that java would be simpler if, instead of everybody talking in terms of treasure maps, what if everybody just talked in terms of treasure itself. This: `String hello = "gold"; x.foo(hello);` means that my code makes a copy of a treasure map that, if you follow it, leads to a treasure chest with `"gold"` in it. But what if instead of all this mess with maps, I just hand the entire treasure chest over?

The problem there is: That's (potentially) a lot of memory, and because that `hello` variable doesn't cease to exist after invoking `x.foo(hello);` that whole copying aspect has to stay, so what you'd be designing is a language where we are making a ton of clones of treasure chests.

That's bad. Treasure maps are easy to copy - they are guaranteed 64-bit (or smaller, on 32-bit VMs and with compressedOOPS tricks a VM can do). A treasure chest could be gigabytes large.

That's why java has no built in way to clone treasures, but clones treasure maps all the time.